# Anybody know what is Nirvana and where we can find it?

Tags: nirvana, buddhadharma

Learning Buddha dharma we need to dive in to the dharma world. Without knowing the truth about Dharma we can not reach our enlightenment.

Comment: I believe this question has been covered in [can-you-explain-nirvana](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/3893/can-you-explain-nirvana) and this question also relates to it [where-does-a-person-go-after-attaining-nirvana](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1963/where-does-a-person-go-after-attaining-nirvana). I can't see anything in this question that wouldn't be covered here. To be honest I'm finding it too vague to be useful or add anything to the site so I'm going to put it on hold. If it can be rephrased so as to be clear what additional information is required

Comment: over and above what is already on the site then it can always be voted for reopening. All the best

Answer (score 1):

It's  hard to know what Nibbana is without experiencing  it. The same as it  can't be known what an orange tastes like until it's taste is experienced, it can only be described with words. It's easier to say what it's not.

Nibbana is not nothingness or annihilation. Nibbana is the highest goal, better than the bliss of Heaven.

Nibbana is a state of great renunciation. There is Heaven within Samsara but it's imperminent and Nibbana is the   final permanent liberation beyond Heaven and outside of Samsara.

Nibbana is an end of the cravings which cause all the suffering of birth, old age, disease, death, lamentation and fear.

Nirvana is the cure for our suffering here in the material world of Samsara caused by craving sensual pleasure and seeing reality as we want to see it rather than how it really is.

It's the correct understandung, virtue, peace and clarity of reality as it really is that leads to Nibbana.

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to the Theravada tradition (or more precisely, the Mahasi tradition), Nibbana is state which is achieved towards the end of the insight cycle (magga-nana and phala-nana, fruition, called also "touch of Nibbana"); it is a state of extinction of consciousness, so there is nothing which can be said about it, there is no experience at all, and only when consciousness reappears, there is the knowledge that something has happened. It is said to have profound effect on the mind in destroying defilements. The state is termed supramundane, since there is nothing "mundane" (no time, no space, no consciousness).

Kenneth Folk talks about this in his excellent inverview at https://batgap.com/kenneth-folk/ .